# How to denote dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am struggling with nomenclature.

If I have matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^4$ it would be considered an element of an 8-dimensonal vector space. If I index $M$ by two indices $i$ and $j$, then what are $i$ and $j$ called? People tend to call these the first and second dimension of $M$ and call $M$ a [2-dimensional array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Multidimensional_arrays) (also [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html)). But, that's confusing because $M$ is supposed to have 8 dimensions.

Note that if I have a vector describing position in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is denoted as a 3-dimensional vector. But, what, then, do you call an array that must be indexed by three indices $M_{ijk}$? It seems - although it seems to be the common trend - that it should not be called a three-dimensional array/matrix because that would conflate the idea of what it means to be a three-dimensional object.

TL;DR: If you have an $\mathbb{R}^l \times \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \times ... \times \mathbb{R}^z$ object, what do you call the total number of $\mathbb{R}$s?

Comment: When talking about data structures, the dimension of an array is what a mathematician calls the *tensor rank*. Probably this notion is exactly what you want.

Comment: It depends on your point of view in general. I agree that such a space would always be called $lmn...z$ dimensional, but the interpretation extends more to how to view the elements of the space. Are they tuples of l,m,n,z - vectors? Or single lmn...z vectors? It's open to interpretation in general as long as the conventions provide for consistent meaning.

Comment: @lisyarus, "tensor rank" removes the ambiguity with regards to calling multiple things "dimensions". But, now the question is, what you call "l" in $\mathbb{R}^l$? Is that the "length" of the first dimension?

Comment: @William, I'm not understand how your comment has helped resolve the issue. I've made my query more clear in the comment above.

Comment: That's definitely, I'm not sure how to explain it clearly myself. I know I have had similar questions before though. For instance, given the vector (1,1,1,1), with the appropriate conventions it can be considered a 4 by 1 matrix, a 1 by 4 matrix, or a point in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which really confused me. Specifically with regards to Riesz Representation theorem and inner product spaces.

Comment: But I like @lisyarus answer because if I remember correctly the notion of tensor rank can be used to differentiate all of these concepts, although I had never thought to connect the two before.

Comment: @fuzzybear3965 Well, I'd call it "dimension of first term of tensor product". Unfortunatelly, I am not aware of some widely-used terminology :(

Comment: @lisyarus, I would like "dimension of first term of tensor product" to be expressed like "capacity of first component" or "length of component one". It's a shame that there isn't good nomenclature for this. Go ahead and merge your comments into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view a multidimensional array, or a multidimensional matrix, is a tensor - an element of the tensor product $$\mathbb{R}^{k_1}\otimes\mathbb{R}^{k_2}\otimes\dots\otimes\mathbb{R}^{k_n}$$

$n$ here is called the *tensor rank*, which is probably the notion you are looking for. I have no knowledge of widely accepted terminology for $k_i$, I'd call it the dimension of the $i$-th term of tensor product, or just the $i$-th dimension.

The terminology for calling $n$ the *dimension* can be explained like this: it is not the dimension of the space, but the dimension of the set of possible indices for the array, which is $\mathbb{N}^n$. So, *dimension* means *dimension as a free commutative monoid*.